# How to create a list of data from a class

Tags: c#

I have a class 'Relation' with property as Child column and parent column.The property child column has details in another class 'Columns' with property such as table name and column name.I need to display the child column_table name and column name in a grid.Thinking of adding it to a list but how to get the details from another class into a list.

Comment: You ought to add simplified code to a question like this. A property cannot "have details in another class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using BindingList or some sort of collection. Also you'll need to qualify the name to the property you want to bind to the grid column, something like: Relation.ChildColumn.TableName, Relation.ChildColumn.ColumnName, and Relation.ParentColumn.TableName, Relation.ParentColumn.ColumnName

Here's a simple example. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection

Also, are you doing this in winforms? If so, and you're using standard grids, you'll have to set the data property names of your columns. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx